# Нужно отсортировать массив в порядке возрастания нормы строк

Tags: c++

Весь день ломаю голову, не понимаю, в чём проблема. Суть задачи в том, чтобы отсортировать строки массива в порядке возрастания суммы цифр каждой строки, если сумма одинакова, строки не менять. На вход дается массив n на m.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, m,a1;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int a[n][m];
    int sum[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum[i]=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j];}}
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            a1=abs(a[i][j]);
            while (a1!=0) {
        sum[i] += a1%10;
                a1 /= 10;}}}
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (sum[i] > sum[i+1]) {
            int t=sum[i];
            sum[i]=sum[i+1];
            sum[i+1]=t;
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        t = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[i+1][j];
                    a[i+1][j] = t;}}}
    
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";}
        cout << endl;}
   
    return 0;
}
```

Сначала я создаю массив sum, в который записываю суммы цифр каждой строки. Потом я проверяю, если первая сумма больше следующей, то я их меняю, и в том же цикле я меняю соответствующие строки с помощью пузырька. Подскажите, где у меня проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не сделали сортировку пузырьком полностью.

Она должна содержать два вложенных цикла, а у вас только один цикл, да ещё с неверным верхним лимитом (`i<n` вызовет нарушение при обращении к `sum[i+1]`), т.е. выполняется только один проход пузырька.

Цикл по j ведь не имеет прямого отношения к сортировке, это просто обмен строк.

```
 for (int k=0; k<n-1; k++) {
      for (int i=n-2; i>=k; i--) {
        if (sum[i] > sum[i+1]) {
            int t=sum[i];
            sum[i]=sum[i+1];
            sum[i+1]=t;
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        t = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[i+1][j];
                    a[i+1][j] = t;}}}}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Какой второй цикл мне нужно составить для полной сортировки? Я же уже использую i как номер строки для обмена, что должен дать второй цикл?

Comment: Добавил........

Comment: Большое спасибо!